# How to Separate 7 segment power supply

Tags: shift-register, 7segmentdisplay

I'm trying to drive a multiplexing double digit 7 segment (5261AS) using Arduino and two shift registers (74595)
I need to separate power supply for the 7 segment to avoid overloading current from the micro.
My question is, should i use transistors to switch power supply for the 7 segment (e.g. using a Darlington array like ULN2003) or powering 74595 vcc from a separate supply other than Arduino's 5v pin is enough?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be just fine if you power the shift registers separately from the micro. Be sure that the grounds are tied together and that both power voltages are similar.

You can run the shift registers at a voltage higher than the micro but not the other way around. In other words, the micro could be running at 3.3V while the shift registers are running at 5V.

Just be sure that you are using the "HCT" version of the chip. Eg. 74HCT595

Comment: Thanks; does HC works too? or it must be exactly HCT ?

Comment: @4r1y4n: 3.3V CMOS output barely reaches the threshold for (high) 5V CMOS input, but handily meets TTL input thresholds.